# what software on a silverlight developer's laptop

Tags: silverlight

i just got a new laptop and probably will be my main keep for the next 3 years.  I am looking for suggestions for software needed for a productive silverlight developer.  In addition to the basics Visual Studio, Blend and the SDK.

Comment: @Justin:  Why should this be a Communit Wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the set of tools you've started with I would add:-

- The Silverlight [Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight) and make sure you keep it up to date.
- Redgate [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) Debugging HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 2):

I would start with everything from the [Get Started](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/) site.

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) is always fun to play with, although a bit outdated, and free. This comes with some nice templates that can be a great learning tool.

Recently I've really been enjoying [Silverlight Spy](http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/) (not free, but there is a trial)

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp) (or another proxy) is a must have for monitoring traffic from your Silverlight application. Check out [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/01/10/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx) post for monitoring localhost traffic.

Additionally, you might want to take a look at the [Composite Application Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF/) (aka Prism) library. This is not something you install, but is great guidance for building Silverlight (and WPF) applications.

Comment: i have used Kaxaml for past WPF work.  will see if they have a newer version.  I am not looking for guidance/frameworks as that would depend on what u are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of SketchFlow, I would say the following:

If you're truly trying to be a productive developer, don't install anything else. That way, you won't be tempted to leave 'the zone'.

Comment: Only if you allow yourself an Internet Connection...haha

Comment: How can you be productive without an internet connection? ;-) Surely you need to deploy your app to your clients and receive feedback in order to improve it.

Comment: @tomlong - That's what your other computer is for!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do data-driven apps, you may be interested in RIA Services.

Answer (score 0):

Solitaire, definitely.

Comment: :)  are u saying it is not part of win 7 ?!

Comment: Well, I know in Vista Business it's hidden (from Games Explorer) until you enable it. :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Kaxaml - I use it quite frequently to get color values, test the widths of things, and other XAML miscellany. It's a lot more light weight than Blend and I am more frequently than not editing XAML in the code editor of Visual Studio.

I don't know if this is the right forum to prove this hypothesis but I think most Silverlight developers edit their XAML in Visual Studio, not Blend which is why having a light weight alternative is handy **some** of the time.

You will need Blend, however, it has no equal for editing control templates / styles.